# query_vars in plugin when using custom permalinks

Tags: plugins, categories

I am trying to do the following

I need to get the category of the current page at the plugin level so before it goes to `archive.php` or`single.php`

so i have a plugin to do this and based upon category it switches themes .. however i am stuggling to get the category at the plugin level when i am using custom permalinks which do not have a query string (ie seo friendly urls)

So if i go to the default permalinks , I can get the category within the plugin using

```
$wp_query->query_vars['cat'];
```

However with the custom permalinks that returns null and I have not been able to think of another way of doing this ,

Please can anyone help ?

Thanks a lot

Waseem

Comment: There is not enough detail here to answer the question. "What plugin are you using?", for example. Post your relevant code alsow.

Answer (score 0):

When pretty permalinks are enabled, the query var is `category_name`:

```
$wp_query->query_vars['category_name'];
```

or use [`get_queried_object`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_queried_object):

```
$this_category = get_queried_object();
echo $this_category->term_id;
echo $this_category->name;
echo $this_category->slug;
// etc..
```

Comment: that solution doesnt work .. $wp_query->query_vars['category_name']; gives null, the other option gives Fatal error: Call to a member function get_queried_object()

Comment: then you'll have to show the context in which you're attempting to use this code

Comment: also, be more specific about what type of query you're trying this on- a category page? if it's a single post, there will be no category query var, as you're not querying a category.

Comment: ok context of the plugin is .. based on category of either archive page or single post page.. i want to show different template , i have all the other stuff working fine .. all i need now is an elegant way to detect category on both these pages starting with the archive page. Its fine using standard permalinks , with non standard ie custom permalinks i am getting null for everything. So ignoring what i do with the category id later on my code is currently var_dump($wp_query->query_vars['category_name']); which gives null. i need the cat id...plugin is activated... etc

Comment: the context meaning where are you attempting to put this code, what action, or is this in a template? have you globalized `$wp_query`?

Comment: additionally, a single post will never have a category query var set, you have to fetch them yourself using the post's ID.